# Displaying Children from a Connected List in a Parent List

Tags: web-part

I have 3 Lists, Site, Product and Module, which are all displayed as List WebParts on a Page.

I only want to show the Site List, which needs to show the Product and it's Modules.  I have connected the Site and Product Lists together, and I can now show the Site and the Products they have.

I don't seem to be able to display the Modules that are within the selected Products.  If I click on the Product within the Site List, the pop-up does display the Modules linked to the Product.

However, ideally I'd like to be able to display the Module in a Column in the Site List WebPart, without the need to click on it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Dave